# How to plot multiple figures in a row using seaborn

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-visualization, seaborn

I have a dataframe `df` that looks like this:

```
df.head()
id        feedback        nlp_model        similarity_score
0xijh4    1               tfidf            0.36
0sdnj7    -1              lda              0.89
kjh458    1               doc2vec          0.78
....
```

I want to plot `similairty_score` versus feedback in a boxplot form using seaborn for each of the unique values in the `model` column: `tfidf`, `lda`, `doc2vec`. My code for this is as follows:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,8))
ax = sns.boxplot(x="feedback", y="similarity_score", data=df[df.nlp_model=='tfidf'])
ax = sns.swarmplot(x="feedback", y="similarity_score", data=df[df.nlp_model=='tfidf'], color="0.25")

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,8))
ax = sns.boxplot(x="feedback", y="similarity_score", data=df[df.nlp_model=='lda'])
ax = sns.swarmplot(x="feedback", y="similarity_score", data=df[df.nlp_model=='lda'], color="0.25")

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,8))
ax = sns.boxplot(x="feedback", y="similarity_score", data=df[df.nlp_model=='doc2vec'])
ax = sns.swarmplot(x="feedback", y="similarity_score", data=df[df.nlp_model=='doc2vec'], color="0.25")

plt.show()
```

The problem is this creates 3 plots one on top of the other.

[image]

How can I generate these same plots but all on a single line, with one axis marking "Similarity Score" on the left most plot only, and "Feedback" axis label directly below each plot?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You are creating new figures, each time you plot. So you can remove all but one of the calls to `plt.subplots()`

The seaborn [`swarmplot()`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.swarmplot.html) and [`boxplot()`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.boxplot.html) accept `ax` arguments i.e. you can tell it which axes to plot to. Therefore, create your figure, subplots and axes using:

```
fig, (ax1, ax2, ax3) = plt.subplots(1, 3)
```

Then you can do something like:

```
sns.boxplot(x="x_vals", y="y_vals", data=some_data, ax=ax1)
```

You can then manipulate the axes as you see fit. For example, removing the y axis labels only on certain subplots etc.

```
fig, (ax1, ax2, ax3) = plt.subplots(1,3,figsize=(10,8))

sns.boxplot(x="feedback", y="similarity_score", data=df[df.nlp_model=='tfidf'], ax=ax1)
sns.swarmplot(x="feedback", y="similarity_score", data=df[df.nlp_model=='tfidf'], color="0.25", ax=ax1)

sns.boxplot(x="feedback", y="similarity_score", data=df[df.nlp_model=='lda'], ax=ax2)
sns.swarmplot(x="feedback", y="similarity_score", data=df[df.nlp_model=='lda'], color="0.25", ax=ax2)

ax2.set_ylabel("")  # remove y label, but keep ticks

sns.boxplot(x="feedback", y="similarity_score", data=df[df.nlp_model=='doc2vec'], ax=ax3)
sns.swarmplot(x="feedback", y="similarity_score", data=df[df.nlp_model=='doc2vec'], color="0.25", ax=ax3)

ax3.set_ylabel("")  # remove y label, but keep ticks

plt.show()
```