# Make two BoxPlot in Seaborn next to each other

Tags: python, seaborn

I have two lists:

```
true = [1,3,5,6,2,5,11,2,4,7,8,9,5,8,13]
fake = [5,3,8,7,5,3,13,8,9,13,15,11,8,9,19]
```

I want to plot this in `Seaborn` as `boxplot`, next to each other with two different colours, red for fake and blue for true. Also, I want vertical boxplot:

```
sns.boxplot(x = "true", y = true, color = "blue")
sns.boxplot(y = "fake", y = fake, color = "fake")
plt.show()
```

Comment: Use matplotlib.subplots - This might be useful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48204780/how-to-plot-multiple-figures-in-a-row-using-seaborn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stacked in same axis:

```
fig,ax = plt.subplots(1)
sns.boxplot(data=true, color = "blue",ax=ax) 
sns.boxplot(data=fake, color = "red",ax=ax) 
plt.show()
```

Comment: I get only some horizontal lines, I do not get vertical plots

Comment: @taga: please see edited answer if it works for your purpose.

Comment: But is there a way to do this on same y scale?
to have both boxplots on 1 y-axis

Comment: @taga: please see edited answer; I think I understand what you mean now...